# My function that calculates the product of two dynamic arrays does not work

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, matrix, product

I wrote a function that calculates the product of two dynamic arrays. My function gives me random numbers instead of the expected result. I have two functions that initialize dynamic matrices A and B. Now, when I try to calculate Dynamic matrix C such that C=A*B, my function does not show the right result. I have checked my code, and it seems that I am doing wrong somewhere, but i cannot figure out exactly where is the problem. Below, I pasted the function that calculates C=A*B. I wrote it in C++ using Dev-C++. Your help will be very appreciated.

```
void CalculateDynamicMatC( double *DynMatA, double *DynMatB, int n)
{
   int i, j, k, m=10; 
   double *DynMatC=new double [m*m] ;


   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
     for( *DynMatC=k=0; k<n; k++)    
      *DynMatC = *(DynMatA)*(*DynMatB);  //where the problem is!!!

    for(int r=0; r<n; r++, cout<<endl)
      for(int c=0; c<n; c++)
        cout << setw(5) << *(DynMatC+n*r+c);
}
```

Comment: You're not using your indices `i,j,k` on the line you've marked "where the problem is." Also, you're not calculating a sum (as you should when doing the matrix product).

Comment: I would suggest reading up on arrays, pointers and their relationship. If you can't find the problem on this one, you clearly lack understanding on how things work.

Answer (score 0):

- You're not using your indices `i,j,k` on the line you've marked "where the problem is."
- The indexing will depend on how you store `DynMatA` and `DynMatB` (row-wise or column-wise).
- You're not calculating a sum (as you should when doing the matrix product).
- You also have memory leak when your function ends.
- You should use a more recent compiler.

Comment: *(DynMatC+n*i+j) = *(DynMatA+n*i+j)*(*DynMatB+n*i+j); this is what i did so far. i am now trying to sum, but i still have some errors.

Comment: @T4000 You have a bug in that code: `(*DynMatB+n*i+j)` is not doing what you think it is. You should be using `v[]` notation anyways. For example, `DynMatA[n*i + j]`.